# Prove for any $[a] \in \mathbb{Z}^\times_n$ multiplication by $[a]$ defines an automorphism $\alpha_{[a]}: \mathbb{Z}_n \to \mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, group-isomorphism

For this we need to show that map $\alpha_{[a]}: \mathbb{Z}_n \to \mathbb{Z}_n$ defined by $\alpha_{[a]}([k]) = [ak]$ is a group isomorphism; that is, a bijective homomorphism. I understand what's required I think I'm just getting a little confused about which elements to use to check the properties specifically. My intuition tells me to check, say, the homomorphism property with the elements $[a],[b] \in \mathbb{Z}_n^\times$ but when I tried that I got: $$\alpha_{[ab]}([k]) = [abk] = [a][bk] = ...$$ where I would imagine we're looking for a product of the form $$[ak][bk] = \alpha_{[a]}([k])\alpha_{[b]}([k])$$ However, if we were to carry out the homomorphism property regarding two elements in the domain $[k],[q] \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ we would get $$\alpha_{[a]}([k+q]) = [a(k+q)] = [ak+aq] = [ak] + [aq] = \alpha_{[a]}([k])\alpha_{[a]}([q])$$ which seems like the homomorphism property is satisfied.

---

So my main question here is which one is correct? Should I be checking these properties (homomorphism, injectivity and surjectivity) against the elements in $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$ (the subscripts) or the elements of the domain $\mathbb{Z}_n$ (the arguments). And how should I go about understanding which one to check various properties against going forward?

Comment: There are a few useful tricks here. You can use that for a finite set $X$ a function $f:X \rightarrow X$ is injective if and only if it's surjective. You can also use that a function is invertible if and only if it's a bijection. See if you can work out why I mention them.

Comment: @CyclotomicField, Well I imagine you mention them since $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a finite group of order $n$ and as such these facts will make it so I only need to prove either surjectivity or injectivity or find an inverse to prove bijectivity. Correct?

Comment: You should precise in your question that you consider $\mathbb Z_n$ as the additive group structure $(\mathbb Z_n,+)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $[a]\in\Bbb Z_n^\times$. You need to show the homomorphism property

$$\alpha_{[a]}([k]+[l])=\alpha_{[a]}([k])+\alpha_{[a]}([l])$$

for all $[k],[l]\in\Bbb Z_n$, together with either surjectivity or injectivity (which are each sufficient to show bijectivity; and bijectivity only holds for $[a]\in\Bbb Z_n^\times$). You also need to show $\alpha_{[a]}$ is *well-defined*, which means that for all $[x],[y]\in\Bbb Z_n$,

$$[x]=[y]\implies \alpha_{[a]}([x])=\alpha_{[a]}([y]).$$

Comment: Okay great. Thanks for the clarification. Is it always the case that we will be verifying these properties against the elements of the domain or the arguments of whatever map we want to show is a morphism or -jective? I feel as though I've seen examples in my text and elsewhere where these properties have been checked against elements in the subscripts of some of these mappings.

Comment: You're welcome, @NumericalDisintegration. You always work with the domain.

Comment: Please notice, @NumericalDisintegration, that I've added another thing to show. It is often overlooked.

Comment: I see. I can, anecdotally, back up your observation that this property is oft overlooked since I do so myself all the time! I'll make sure to prove this property. I appreciate the fastidiousness @Shaun.

Comment: @Shaun Bijectivity follows from the hypothesis $[a] \in \mathbb Z_n^\times$. Otherwise, it doesn't hold.

Comment: Indeed, yes, @mathcounterexamples.net. I don't see where I said otherwise though.

Comment: You didn't, but I would suggest that you explicitely state it in the answer to avoid the OP thinking that it holds whatever $[a]$ is, which is not.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the suggestion. I have edited my answer accordingly, @mathcounterexamples.net.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you don't bother with the specific case of $\mathbb Z_n$. Just prove that for any ring $(R, + , \cdot)$ and $a \in R$ the map

$$\varphi_a: x \mapsto ax$$ is a homomorphism of the group $(R, +)$. That is easy and will avoid cumbersome notations.

Then you have to prove that for $[a] \in \mathbb Z_n^\times$, $\alpha_{[a]}$ is bijective. And that is quite easy as by definition, it exists $[b] \in \mathbb Z_n^\times$ such that $[b][a]= [1]$ and therefore $\alpha_{[b]}$ is the inverse of $\alpha_{[a]}$.